# 4 Wii Remotes with Unity3D

Tags: javascript, macos, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, wiimote

Is there a way for me to connect multiple wii remotes to my Mac and use them to control my game in Unity? If there isn't a direct solution, is there a way to implement a bluetooth interface into Unity and understand the commands used to read and control the Wii Remote. Sorry if this is a bit vague. I only use javascript in Unity and I plan to make a multiplayer platformer.

Currently I can use Packet Logger supplied by Developer.Apple and read the information coming from my wiiremote button presses but that is as far as I can get.

If that is too hard, maybe someone can suggest a way to translate wii remote button presses into keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect Wii Remote to Unity on your Mac. You need to learn C# though. This is what you need

https://github.com/Flafla2/Unity-Wiimote

It works for Mac, Windows and Linux.

Comment: Ok I will try this out. I can't believe I have never found this...  And why was my question disliked?

Comment: It also has  a Unity project attached to it. You can download the whole project and see how it is made. If this answered your question, you can close this question by accepting this answer.

Comment: Well I can't access my computer now. Gotta wait and go home.